# Generating network from two matrix with different color in R

Tags: r, networking, plot, social-networking

I have two matrices `m1` and `m2` as follows:

```
m1<-matrix(sample(0:1,36,replace=TRUE),nc=6);
diag(m1)<-0
row.names(m1) <- c(paste0("X",1:6))
colnames(m1) <- c(paste0("X",1:6))

m2<-matrix(sample(0:1,36,replace=TRUE),nc=6);
diag(m2)<-0
row.names(m2) <- c(paste0("X",1:6))
colnames(m2) <- c(paste0("X",1:6))
```

where value 1 represent a connection between corresponding variables.
I can easily generate a network for one of such matrix using packages like igraph. However, I am interested in generating a differential network using both matrix such that the edges are colored. It would be like overlapping two networks such that 'green' represent edges that are both m1 and m2, 'blue' represent edges that are in m2 but not in m1, and black edges represent connection in m1 but not in m1. Is there some command for generating such network, similar to 'lines/points' for simple overlapping plot, in R?

Answer (score 0):

First, we create an edge list from your adjacency matrices. We do this my adding them together in such a way that those edges only in `m1` have a value of 1, those only in `m2` have a value of 2, and those in both have a value of 3.

```
m3<-m1+2*m2
el<-subset(as.data.frame(as.table({m3[lower.tri(m3)]<-0; m3})), Freq>0)
names(el)<-c("V1","V2","CON")
```

Now we can create a graph object and color in the edges using the values we encoded above

```
library(igraph)
gg<-graph.data.frame(el, directed=F)
plot(gg, edge.color=c("black","blue","green")[E(gg)$CON])
```

This will give you the following plot

[image: graph with color edges based on two adjacency matrices]

Comment: Thank you Mr. flick! this is indeed tricky. But, what if instead of 0 and 1 we have have weighted data between 0 and 1; or may be between -1 and 1. I think this approach won't work in those cases. for such cases we would need some "overlapping network" kind of function

Answer (score 0):

```
library(igraph)
ml <- list(m1,m2)
gl <- lapply(ml,graph.adjacency, weighted=T)
g  <- do.call("+",gl)
cols <- c("black","blue","green")
colors <- cols[as.numeric(!is.na(E(g)$weight_1)) + 2*(!is.na(E(g)$weight_2))]
set.seed(1)    # for reproducible graph
plot(g, edge.color=colors)
```

[image]

Your matrices `m1` and `m2` are not symmetrical, which implies a directed graph. So in this case the graph shows that `m1` has a connection from `X2` to `X4`, whereas `m2` has a connection from `X4` to `X2`.

This approach takes advantage of the fact that you can add graphs, and that the result has edges with attributes from both of the original graphs (here, `weight_1` and `weight_2`). It also deals with the possibility that the weights are not 0 or 1.

Comment: Hi Howard, Thanks for replying. Actually my matrices are symmetrical and I wanted to report same. However, I forgot to paste two extra lines 't1 <- lower.tri(m1)' and 'm1[t1] <- t(m1)[t1]'. Your answer provided more learning to me.